# VDO on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, duplicates, redhat

Is it possible to use VDO on Kubernetes(with Docker containers)?

As far as I know, block devices are mountable - the problem here(I think) would be loading the VDO modules into the Docker container. I assume it's not possible to do it within the Docker container, so the responsibility lies on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it's not directly supported by [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) but you can always manage your VDO modules and [volumes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/vdo-quick-start) at the host level. For example, mount the volumes under /mnt/vdo0 and then use them in a container with the [`HostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume option.

You can also, for example, specify a VDO volume as the main graph directory for your [docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) with something like `/usr/bin/dockerd -g /mnt/vdo0` That will make your images and your non-external volume container storage stored in that directory.